# Is there any way to detect power state of Display device that USB Stick PC Connected?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-10

I developed application on `WPF`, it will run on **Windows 10 Stick PC** connected to **any display device**. Is there any way to **detect if Display device turn on or off**? I searched in SO, but didn't find answer.

**NOTE:** In my case Stick PC connected to display device via HDMI and Stick PC has its own Power supply

Comment: No. The port on the side of the display device is a simple USB port. It has no knowledge of where it's siltting.

Comment: It's not really obvious what you are trying to ask here, since this appears to be a hardware question and not a code question.  The simple answer, however, is that those Stick PCs don't have their own power supply, they power from the bus they are connected to; ergo if the display device is turned off (or in low power mode), the PC itself is off as well, and can't be running any program to detect anything.

Comment: I edited my answer, Stick PC has its own power supply. And my question is how can I determine display device power state programmatically, it's not hardware question

Comment: I saw it happen once at a friend's place: when he turned off the external TV, the attached laptop would automatically revert to non-extended desktop. I suspect it's a hardware-specific feature of some kind, because it doesn't happen on my desktop rig when I turn off the HDMI monitor...

Comment: unfortunately, it *is* a hardware question;  even if the machine is able to stay on, detecting if the display is active or not is the job of the Video Card;  whether or not you are able to even know the status of the Video Output is dependent on what kind of Video Card is in use, what drivers are in use, and if the Video Card Manufacturer allows programmatic access to this information.  There isn't a standardized WPF function or library to supply this information.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no "monitor off" event.

Depending on the type of display, the internal USB hub simply loses its power when the display is turned off, making the according drive letter of the inserted USB stick disappear.

So get the startup path, and check whether the drive letter of that path is still available.

Comment: while this is accurate, it's not exactly a match to the question;  As I said in my other comment, it's not obvious from the question because this is a hardware question, but the question is about a PC that runs entirely on a stick, not a usb storage.